# random uppercase in a word + multiple string insert

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I really need a solution for the next scenario(I've been searching for hours and beating about the bushes to find a smooth solution, but none worked):

I have a winform that:

- parse a text file
- generate some folders using random words from that file

My code so far:

```
int value;
string path = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (fbd.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        path = fbd.SelectedPath;

    }
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);//store the value from the textbox in variable "value"
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (path != null && Directory.Exists(path))
        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string tick1 = rnd.Next(0, 10).ToString();

            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"M:\\dictionar.txt");
            var r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            var randomLineNumber = r.Next(0, lines.Length - 1);
            var line = lines[randomLineNumber];

            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
            {
                char c = line[j];
                if (rnd.Next(2) == 0)
                {
                    c = Char.ToUpper(c);
                }
                b.Append(c);
                if (j % 3 == 2)
                {
                    b.Append(rnd.Next(10));
                }
            }
            line = b.ToString();

            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, string.Format("{0}", line.Insert(2, tick1).Insert(4, tick1).Insert(6, tick1))));
        }
}
```

Is there a way to use `ToUpper()` method as `line.Insert()` one so that I can get random upper letters? More, is there a better way of randomizing those index positions form `line.Insert()` (I'm asking this because when it's generating the folders name: the indexes are the same: e.g pe8rs8on8al and just after that the index changes.)?
I want to achieve the following:

if I have the next words in the .txt file:

personal
football
programming
computer

I would like the folder names to look like:

Pe3rs9oN1al
fO8ot5Ba6lL

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the characters in the string and build a new string depending on random values:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++ ) {
  char c = line[i];
  if (rnd.Next(2) == 0) {
    c = Char.ToUpper(c);
  }
  b.Append(c);
  if (i % 2 == 1) {
    b.Append(rnd.Next(10));
  }
}
line = b.ToString();
```

Note: You shouldn't create `Random` objects in the loop. You should create a single `Random` object before the loop and use for all random numbers that you need. Creating instances too close in time will make them return the same sequences of random numbers. Also, you don't need to seed the random generator from the clock, the constructor without parameters does that automatically:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

So, the code in the method would be:

```
if (path != null && Directory.Exists(path))
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"M:\\dictionar.txt");
        var randomLineNumber = rnd.Next(0, lines.Length);
        var line = lines[randomLineNumber];

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
        {
            char c = line[j];
            if (rnd.Next(2) == 0)
            {
                c = Char.ToUpper(c);
            }
            b.Append(c);
            if (j % 2 == 1)
            {
                b.Append(rnd.Next(10));
            }
        }
        line = b.ToString();

        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, line));
    }
}
```

Note the `rnd.Next(0, lines.Length)` to pick a random line. The upper limit for the random number is not inclusive, so if you use `rnd.Next(0, lines.Length - 1)` it will never pick the last line.

Comment: It worked. But I have a question: how do I re-write just one random object instead of mine, before the loop, so that everything will work as expected ?

Would you be kind and make the necessary changes to the updated post ? I don't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @Alexander: I added the code above. Oh, and please don't replace the original question, it makes the existing answers look strange. Add the updated code intstead of replacing the code.

Comment: Ok, sure. Thank you very much for your help @Guffa. Is there a way to make some kind of a pattern when inserting random digits ? I mean, I want the word to be 2 letter + 1 digit + 2 letter + 1 digit ... and so on until it reaches the end. At the moment, it's weird because it is adding more digits instead of one ( this is the reason for having multiple `randoms()`

Comment: @Alexander: the `if (j % 2 == 1)` does that pattern (I changed it from `if (j % 3 == 2)`). The condition is true for every other character, so it adds a digit there. Note that there is just `Path.Combine(path, line)` to create the directory name, if you keep the `Insert` calls there they will add even more digits to the string.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are specifying only tick1 in the same loop. If you want to change this, add additional ticks to your code as below:

```
string tick1 = rnd.Next(0, 10).ToString();
string tick2 = rnd.Next(0, 10).ToString();
string tick3 = rnd.Next(0, 10).ToString();
```

Then use those in your formatting of the string:

```
 Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, string.Format("{0}", line.Insert(2, tick1).Insert(4, tick2).Insert(6, tick3))))
```

Comment: Thank you, but just so you know, there's no big difference using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got like this

[image]

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string content = "";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\names.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] names = content.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        string path = "D:\\RandDirs";
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))Directory.CreateDirectory(path) ;

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\" + getRandomName(names));
    }

    Random randName = new Random();
    Random insertingNumber = new Random();
    Random randUpper = new Random();
    Random randInsertNumber = new Random();
    string getRandomName(string[] names)
    {
        string name = names[randName.Next(names.Length)];
        name = name.Replace(" ", "");
        string result = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
            result += (randUpper.Next(0, 9) <= 5 ? name[i].ToString().ToLower() : name[i].ToString().ToUpper())
            + (((i + 1) % 2 == 0) ? insertingNumber.Next(0, 9).ToString() : "");
        return result;
    }
```

as per your needs, i've changed from randomly inserting numbers to inserting number every 2 characters.

Comment: if you'd like, look at the updated code from my initial post and try to adapt your code to it while I am trying other solutions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Like Guffa said you should not use Random in a loop, in all preference you should only instanciate one of it, but I think you could use it like this

```
public static class StringRandomize
{
    static readonly Random rnd = new Random();
    static char[] permmitedCharacters { get; set; }

    static StringRandomize()
    {
        List<char> Chars=  new List<char>();
        for (int i = 48; i < 48+10; i++)
        {
            Chars.Add((char)i);
        }
        for (int i = 65; i < 65+26; i++)
        {
            Chars.Add((char)i);
        }
        permmitedCharacters = Chars.ToArray();
    }

    public static string Randomize(string input, double RandomizePercent = 30)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int index = 0;
        while (index < input.Length)
        {

            if (rnd.Next(0, 100) <= RandomizePercent)
            {
                if (rnd.Next(0, 100) <= RandomizePercent)
                {
                    result.Append(GenerateCaracter());
                }
                else
                {
                    if (rnd.Next(0, 100) > 50)
                    {
                        result.Append(input.ToLower()[index]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.Append(input.ToUpper()[index]);
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result.Append(input[index]);
                index++;
            }
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }

    private static char GenerateCaracter()
    {
        return permmitedCharacters[rnd.Next(0, permmitedCharacters.Length)];
    }
}


    private static void GenerateRandomDirectories(string path, int value)
    {
        //I'm supposing value is the number of lines that you want
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"M:\\dictionar.txt");
        Random rnd = new Random();
        if (path != null && Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\" + StringRandomize.Randomize(lines[rnd.Next(0,lines.Length)]));
            }
        }
    }
```

> "pers3o7Nal"
>
> "foOtBaLl"

Comment: If you add column ':', then he can't use it for creating Directory

Comment: I edited the initial post and added all the code: basically: 
    I have two buttons and one TextBox.
    The first button event is supposed to use FolderBrowserDialog and let me choose a specific a folder.Then, to save its path in a variable.
    The text box is supposed to get as a value the number of folders that I want to create in the choosen path.
    The second button is going to create the number of folders(with different name each) written in the textbox at the first button specified path.